# split word into array within array for each word

Tags: php, arrays

I try to split a word per letter and put each one of the letters within the previous array.

code:

```
$array = [];
$word = "test";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++){
    //  $array[$word[$i]] = ...
    }
```

I failed to understand how to keep "reference" to the previous array..

What I try to get  (word: "test"):

```
    Array
    (
        [t] => Array
            (
                [e] => Array
                    (
                       [s] => Array
                           (
                             [t]
                             [word] => "test"
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: Why would you even want/need to do that?

Comment: @TheBlueDog Does it matter? There either is or isn't a solution to the problem. Why he wants to do this should be irrelevant.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: That depends on whether he wants an answer to his question or an answer to his **problem**. Big difference.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I like your approach. I want to learn myself how to solve my problem. the thing is, right now I am stuck at this specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://eval.in/243876

```
$word = "test";
$wordarray = str_split($word);
$result = array();
$tmp = array();


foreach($wordarray as $i => $letter) {
    if($i==0) {
        $tmp[$wordarray[strlen($word)-($i+1)]]["word"] = $word;
    } else {
    $tmp = array();
        $tmp[$wordarray[strlen($word)-($i+1)]] = $result;
    }
    $result = $tmp;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Or a more elegant way:

```
<?php

$word = "test";
$wordarray = array_reverse(str_split($word));
$result = array();
$tmp = array();


foreach($wordarray as $i => $letter) {
    if($i == 0) {
        $tmp[$letter]["word"] = $word;
    } else {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp[$letter] = $result;
    }
    $result = $tmp;
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://eval.in/243937

Output

```
array(1) {
  ["t"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["e"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["s"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["t"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["word"]=>
          string(4) "test"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output for word 'honorificabilitudinitatibus':

```
array(1) {
  ["h"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["o"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["n"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["o"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["r"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["i"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["f"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["i"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["c"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["a"]=>
                    array(1) {
                      ["b"]=>
                      array(1) {
                        ["i"]=>
                        array(1) {
                          ["l"]=>
                          array(1) {
                            ["i"]=>
                            array(1) {
                              ["t"]=>
                              array(1) {
                                ["u"]=>
                                array(1) {
                                  ["d"]=>
                                  array(1) {
                                    ["i"]=>
                                    array(1) {
                                      ["n"]=>
                                      array(1) {
                                        ["i"]=>
                                        array(1) {
                                          ["t"]=>
                                          array(1) {
                                            ["a"]=>
                                            array(1) {
                                              ["t"]=>
                                              array(1) {
                                                ["i"]=>
                                                array(1) {
                                                  ["b"]=>
                                                  array(1) {
                                                    ["u"]=>
                                                    array(1) {
                                                      ["s"]=>
                                                      array(1) {
                                                        ["word"]=>
                                                        string(27) "honorificabilitudinitatibus"
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: added more elegent way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = 'test';

$root = [];
$array = &$root;

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++){
    $ch = $word[$i];
    $new = [];
    $array[$ch] = &$new;
    $array = &$new;
}

$array['word'] = $word;

print_r($root);
```

I have no idea why you'd want to do this though, are you trying to make a trie?